# Issue while working with subdomains in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app in `Rails 5` with `Ruby 2.4.0`.

My app is running subdomains based off of an account which a user belongs to (an account will also have many users associated to it). what I am trying to accomplish is locking down the subdomains so that a user can only log into or hit a subdomain that exists in the account model. If the subdomain dose not exist then they should be redirected to the account create page.

I have a method right now in my application controller of the following:

```
  def require_account!
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url(subdomain: 'www') if !@account.present?
  end
```

it gives me this before_action I can drop into my controllers to prevent someone from seeing the object but when I'm logged into the app I can be on `thisdomain.lvh.me:3000/some_page` and then enter `anotherdomain.lvh.me:3000/some_page` and still see my account data. When i am logged in as a user i can also jump between other domains. This to me is sloppy and I would like to prevent this from happening (preferably with out the use of the apartment gem as much of my application is publicly shared. Ive tried to find some tutorials on this but to no avail. when I log out and login as a different user the same thing happens but with their data set.

Any assistance, suggestions or help here would be greatly appreciated! please let me know if you require any further assistance here!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add another before_action

```
def authorize_user_domain!
  return unless @account&.has_subdomain?(current_subdomain) 
  render_404
end
```

I assume account.rb has subdomains association, so the code there would look similar to:

```
def has_subdomain?(subdomain)
  subdomains.include?(subdomain)
end
```

And I think it is also good to have `current_subdomain` helper method in application controller

Answer (score 1):

Use devise? Also ActsAsTenant.

Then set tenant in the controller with the custom method based on the subdomain they are using. Include in the devise sessions controller that if a user doesn't belong to the current tenant (already set first before log in) send them back out to the sign up page.

[Acts as tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant)